# How can I make this php snippet float:right in my footer, but remain in the body of the page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to have these social icons **float:right** in my footer.  But when I try **this** before the closing PHP tag ?>:

```
<span style="float:right;"><?php if ( function_exists('cn_social_icon') ) echo 
cn_social_icon(); ?></span>
```

It gives me:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/jpweber/public_html/footer.php 
on line 33
```

If I put it **below** the closing PHP tag, ?>, it works, but appears **outside** the body of the page, way in the lower right-hand corner of the screen (in the blue area).

I'd like it within the body of the page, but I'd like to get it to float to the right.  The only way I can get it to show up within the body is to use this above the closing php tag:

```
if ( function_exists('cn_social_icon') ) echo cn_social_icon();
```

**below** the closing ?>.  But then it doesn't **float:right**.
[image]

So I'll have to implement some code somewhere in the footer, which is currently this, what you see in the picture, where **if ( function_exists('cn_social_icon') ) echo cn_social_icon();** is just mixed in there:

```
<?php
/**
 * Builds the footer structure.
 *
 * @package Catalyst
 */

global $catalyst_layout_id;
if ( function_exists('cn_social_icon') ) echo cn_social_icon();
if( !is_page_template( 'template-blank-body.php' ) )
{
catalyst_hook_before_before_footer( $catalyst_layout_id . '_catalyst_hook_before_before_footer' );
catalyst_hook_before_footer( $catalyst_layout_id . '_catalyst_hook_before_footer' );
catalyst_hook_after_before_footer( $catalyst_layout_id . '_catalyst_hook_after_before_footer' );
catalyst_hook_footer( $catalyst_layout_id . '_catalyst_hook_footer' );

catalyst_hook_before_after_footer( $catalyst_layout_id . '_catalyst_hook_before_after_footer' );
catalyst_hook_after_footer( $catalyst_layout_id . '_catalyst_hook_after_footer' );
catalyst_hook_after_after_footer( $catalyst_layout_id . '_catalyst_hook_after_after_footer' );
}
wp_footer();

catalyst_hook_after_html( $catalyst_layout_id . '_catalyst_hook_after_html' );

/**
 * Un-comment the below function to list all items currently hooked into a WordPress or Catalyst hook.
 */
//catalyst_list_hooked();
/**
 * Un-comment the below function to display the number of database queries during the WordPress execution.
 */
//echo get_num_queries();
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: post the the entire contents of footer.php

Comment: Thanks Nicholas; I edited the question to include the entire footer.  Appreciate you taking the time to try to help!

Comment: Using this footer.php, you still get that error at line 33?

Comment: Using this footer, I get the result as displayed in the picture; I can't get it to float:right ....

Comment: You need to hook your call to echo into the correct hook. I don't know which one it would be, I'd try them all one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly which hook you're looking for, but try all of them using the following format:

Replace:

```
if ( function_exists('cn_social_icon') ) echo cn_social_icon();
```

With:

```
function add_social_icons() {
    if ( function_exists('cn_social_icon') ) echo cn_social_icon();
}
add_action($catalyst_id.'_catalyst_hook_before_before_footer', 'add_social_icons');
```

Comment: Trying various hooks in various places ... not getting an error, but nothing is showing up ... and when I view the html output, nothing is in there signifying any social media icons or links.  I'll keep trying!  Thanks again Nicholas!

Comment: Does `template-blank-body.php` exist in your theme folder?

Comment: Yes ... all it is ... is this:  <?php
/*
Template Name: Blank Body
*/

/**
 * Call to the catalyst_framework() function.
 * 
 * What this function does is check to see where it is being called from
 * and then returns the type of content that corresponds with such a location,
 * which in this case is template-blank-body.php, Catalyst's "Blank Body" Page Template.
 *
 * @package Catalyst
 */
 
catalyst_framework();

Comment: hrm... I don't know enough about Catalyst to help further. I'd suggest getting support from its developers - http://catalysttheme.com/ Sorry.

Comment: It's okay .. thanks for helping, Nicholas.  I put <span style="float:right;"><?php if ( function_exists('cn_social_icon') ) echo cn_social_icon(); ?></span> just above the beginning <?php tag at the top of the page, and it floats to the right now, although it's not really in the footer ... but it's better than it was.  Thanks again!